# Randomised resource rarity in Subnautica

Tags: subnautica

I have noticed in certain playthroughs in Subnautica that sometimes there are fewer resources of a particular type, an example being in one playthrough I could find hardly any large quartz deposits and vast amounts of large titanium deposits.  Is this normal?

Answer (score 2):

Having played the game start-to-finish a dozen or more times, I'd have to say yes, you are at the RNG's mercy. I did find that some biomes seem to have a higher likelihood of various resources -- for quartz I always go into the red grassy area (I forget what it's called offhand) and there seems to be quite a lot of it there. Same with the Sandstone nodes - there seems to be way more of them in the red grassy area (grassy plateaus maybe?) than in the kelp forest, not to mention they are easier to find because it's relatively flat. Sometimes I can hardly find any quartz at all in the safe shallows, and end up hitting the grassy plateaus very early in the game, even before I get the little hand-held jet thing.